# How to select Items with a where alt != "someString"

Tags: jquery

I am selecting a group of checkboxes like so

```
$(tbl).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
```

I want to EXCLUDE any checkboxes that have an alt="disabled" property and I can't get it to work, can anyone help.

Comment: As a Note: `<Input>` tags do not have an attribute called `alt`. To produce valid HTML use a custom `data`-attribute like `data-alt="disabled"` or use one of the standard attributes for input fields of type `checkbox`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$(tbl).find('input[type=checkbox][alt!="disabled"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
```

I always tend to use the filter function myself:

```
$(tbl).find('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('alt') != 'disabled';
}).prop('checked', this.checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(tbl).find('input[type=checkbox]')
      .not('[alt=disabled]')
      .prop('checked', this.checked);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LtgtZ/)